# Passing parameter externally to a TestNG class

Tags: testing, automation, testng

My @DataProvider looks up some restful url as below.
@DataProvider(name = "dbconfig")
    public Object[][] provideDbConfig() {
        Map map = SwaggerUtility.getSwaggerData("http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json");

I ideally want a way to pass the url externally to the TestNG run or class.
Is there a way to do that?
Ideally the tests would be integrated with some CI tool which needs to pass the parameter down to the TestNG job.
I do not see a way to pass parameters directly to a TestNG class.
Please let me know if there is a way around

Comment: You want to pass it to your dataprovider or entire class?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as an argument as a system level property - read it in your beforeclass method using System.getProperty("nameOfProp") and set a variable as you need for your class.